# Create cursor for temporary table in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor

I have some data inserted into the temporary table and I want to show **COUNT** in a LOOP by using `CURSOR`

Here is the temp table:-

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
 FROM (
select distinct a.CUser_id, b.User_Id, b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name NAME
from inward_doc_tracking_trl a, user_mst b
where a.CUser_id = b.mkey
and CStatus_flag = 1
and NStatus_flag = 4
) AS x
Select * from #temp order by NAME
```

[![TEMP TABLE data][1]][1]

I am new to cursor, kindly help

I am using `sql server 2005`

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "I want to show COUNT in a LOOP" ? Do you want to display incrementation? What is the purpose that you want to use a Cursor?

Comment: Ok so you have the above temp table with RECEIVED column set to 0. You want the Cursor to run through each of those records (rows) and update the RECEIVED column based on a certain validation?

Comment: Please give me the validation detail. Would like to have a look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per our discussion in chat :

```
DECLARE @Count INT


SELECT * 
            INTO #temp
             FROM (
            select distinct a.CUser_id, b.User_Id, b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name AS NAME, 0 AS RECEIVED 
            from inward_doc_tracking_trl a, user_mst b
            where a.CUser_id = b.mkey
            and CStatus_flag = 1
            and NStatus_flag = 4
            ) AS x


DECLARE Cur_1 CURSOR
    FOR SELECT CUser_id, User_Id FROM #temp


OPEN Cur_1
DECLARE @CUser_id INT
DECLARE @User_Id INT
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 
INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN

        SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM inward_doc_tracking_trl
        WHERE CUser_id = @CUser_id 
        AND NStatus_flag = 4 
        AND CStatus_flag = 1 
        AND a.U_datetime BETWEEN '01/04/2016' AND GETDATE()

        UPDATE #temp
        SET RECEIVED = @Count
        WHERE CUser_id = @CUser_id
        AND User_Id = @User_Id

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_1 INTO @CUser_id, @User_Id
        END
CLOSE Cur_1
DEALLOCATE Cur_1

SELECT * FROM #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```